# Unable to connect to phpmyadmin on other server

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a website hosting on www.host1free.com. Earlier I had connected to MySQL database of the host.

Now I am having my own VPS which is accessed by ip address 5.231.36.181. I have also installed phpmyadmin. All works fine within the server.

Now I want to connect my website database to the MySQL server on 5.231.36.181.

The database on the server is accessed by **5.231.36.181/phpmyadmin**
and the database on host is accessed by **sql12.1freehosting.com/phpmyadmin**

How to connect the database to my VPS phpmyadmin ?

Comment: I hope you made these locations up and are not sharing your paths?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatever the details you are using for logging in to your phpmyadmin use the same usename and password for connecting to database

secondly host can be localhost or your VPS IP Address

[image: PHP MY ADMIN Panel TOP]

The rectangle marked in red contains your IP ,

1. Use the IP Address of the server and Username and password that you used to login if you are still not getting it post us what you have tried and what error you are getting

connecting to mysql database

```
// Define database connection constants
define('DB_HOST', 'your IP');
define('DB_USER', 'Your DB USER');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'db user Password');
define('DB_NAME', 'your dbname');

$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
or die('cannot connect to   MYSQL');
```

if you are confused you can create a new database user assign the database to the particular user and can use the details to connect to your DB Cheers

Comment: I am using my VPS IP Adress for the same, but nothing special happen other than error

Answer (score 0):

You connect your website to MySql database, not to PhpMyAdmin. Enter Host as `localhost`, username and password. If localhost is not working, try entering IP of database. There must be statet somewhere what params to use to connect to database

Answer (score 0):

Use Your Mysql Details and connect to your dataBase like this:

```
mysqli_connect('5.231.36.181',username,password,dbname);
```

Comment: I did the same but nothing happens.